# R: Split data frame into list of data frames in manner of groupBy

Tags: r

I want to split a data frame into a list of data frames in the manner of groupBy.  I currently have the following code:

```
infrastructure_by_day <- read.csv("allInfrastructure.csv")

countries <- levels(infrastructure_by_day$country)
categories <- levels(infrastructure_by_day$category)

segregate <- function(country, category) {
  infrastructure_by_day[
    which(infrastructure_by_day$country == country & 
            infrastructure_by_day$category == category), ]
}

infrastructure_data_frames <- mapply(segregate, countries, categories)
```

However this gives me a list of lists.

```
> typeof(infrastructure_data_frames)
[1] "list"
> typeof(infrastructure_data_frames[1])
[1] "list"
```

How can I get a list of data frames?

Comment: You may want to check `class(infrastructure_data_frames[1])` instead. `typeof(a data frame)` returns a list.

Comment: You could also use `interaction` and `split`: `infrastructure_by_day$countryCats <- with(infrastructure_by_day, interaction(country, category))` which gives an interacted factor. Then use `infrastructure_data_frames <- split(infrastructure_by_day, infrastructure_by_day$countryCats)` to get the list.

Comment: Thanks!  That works perfect.  Why don't you write it up as a proper answer?