# Split and drop grouping variable

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, negation

I am trying to split a data frame into a list. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235067/r-split-data-frame-into-list-of-data-frames-in-manner-of-groupby) was helpful, but I also want to drop the column used for grouping, since it will mess up future steps. The `drop` argument for `split` only applies to unused levels. The data frame is as follows:

```
structure(list(Var1 = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L,
                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                         -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
               Var2 = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 
                        0L, 0L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                        -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L,
                        -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L),
               Var3 = c(1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 
                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                        -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
               Var4 = c(1L, -1L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                        1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                        -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
               Var5 = c(1L, -1L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
                        1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
                        0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, 
                        -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L), 
               Bin = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
                       7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
                       12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 
                       16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L)), 
           .Names = c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "Var4", "Var5", "Bin"), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -35L))
```

How can I split this by "Bin" while dropping "Bin"?

Comment: If you're interested in using a package, there's `library(data.table); setDT(DF); split(DF, by="Bin", keep=FALSE)`

Comment: A key concept to remember is that you cannot use the "-" (minus sign) in front of character values. That only works with numeric vectors (which can be constructed with `grep` or `which`) , and you can only use "!" with logical vectors which you construct with `grepl` or `%in%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your information about this column, you may use

```
split(df[, -ncol(df)], df$Bin)
```

if you know that it's the last one, and

```
split(df[, !names(df) == "Bin"], df$Bin)
```

if you only know its name. Also

```
split(df[, -which(names(df) == "Bin")], df$Bin)
```

and

```
split(df[, -match("Bin", names(df))], df$Bin)
```

Comment: also `!grepl("Bin", names(df) )`  or `-grep("Bin", names(df)`